# How can I copy my old inactive website saved on web.archive.org and import it to a new active website

Tags: html, ftp, web, mirror

http://web.archive.org/web/20140517091644/http://goodsoloads.com/

I used to have a website that I shut down after about a year. The captured (inactive) webpage is linked above via Web Archive. How do I download the data captured above and re-upload it into a new active website, so it is exactly like the Web Archive snapshot but instead it is live and all links work.

How do I reupload it back to the new site? FTP? What are the steps to uploading the data to my host?

Basically, I want to copy the entire old website from web.archive.org, and have it on a new active website with the exact same content as the Archive snapshot link above.

Comment: There are web scraping tools you can use which would download a page and the resources it uses and links to.  Some browsers will even download the resources when you just "Save As" while viewing the page.  However, recommendations for such tools are not really on-topic for Stack Overflow.  (Unless you're writing your own web scraper for this task and have encountered a problem in that project, we can help with that.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a straightforward task, there are several "moving parts" here to be addressed. I will give you an overview, but based on your question, I believe you will need some professional help to get this up and running again:

- Retrieve html pages + images: this you can do by saving the pages to your hard drive (save as html complete). Go page by page and save them in a folder.
- Establish a web hosting account somewhere, and tie it to the new domain name you want to use.
- Upload (via ftp) the pages and images to the new server. You might want to put all images in a separate folder and change the page code to address the new path for the images.
- Server side functionalities: you will have to redo (re-link, or redo the code) your shopping cart, as this is a functionality that depends on a server. You will also need to redo the contact emails (recreate with new domain name) and recreate/adapt any contact form code or other server side functionality you might have there.

This is just a rough, non-exhaustive guideline of what you need to do to get this up and running again. Based on your question, I believe you will better served by hiring someone to oversee the project -- some web hostings offer free migration services when you sign up, contact them before signing up and ask if they can help you to get this up and running -- that might give you the best possible deal in this situation. Good luck!